# how to display value image on edit in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[I use carrierwave gem to upload images, how to display images on edit file in rails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GXNC.png)

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrevS.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GXNC.png)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to show image into edit form

```
<%= simple_form_for @product do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= image_tag f.object.image if f.object.image.present? %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

you could use the [simple_form](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form) gem

Comment: yeah, thank you. But I want to add element to add more images and not display.

Comment: maybe this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amT27SfNhKM) could help.